# Google ReCaptcha in Validation Attribute

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, recaptcha

I am trying to figure out how to integrate Google ReCaptcha into my validatoin Attribute.  Here is examples of my code:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (!IsRequired) return ValidationResult.Success;

    var baseResult = base.IsValid(value, validationContext);

    if (baseResult != ValidationResult.Success)
    {
        return baseResult;
    }

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var response = client.DownloadString(string.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}&remoteIp={2}", _privateKey, value, GetIpAddress()));
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RecaptchaResponse>(response).Success;
        return result ? ValidationResult.Success : new ValidationResult(ValidationResource.CaptchaInvalid);
    }
}
```

The problem that I am having is that the Value is always null. I understand why the value is null, however, I do not understand how to set the actual value.

Inside my HTML I have:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ReCaptchaToken" name="ReCaptchaToken" />
<div id="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="dark" data-sitekey="stuff"></div>
```

The Validation Attribute is set on ReCaptchaToken.  The value of ReCaptchaToken is currently not set so the value inside my Class will always be null.

What I do not understand is how to set value of ReCaptchaToken upon form submission.  I have tried doing something like this:

```
document.getElementById("ReCaptchaToken").value = document.getElementById("g-Recaptcha-Response").value;
```

However, this will crash my javascript every time.  I assume this is because `g-Recaptcha-Response` is inside the IFrame?

I am trying to create an independent validation DLL for validation, so I cannot get the value by passing it from a controller as the validation happens before the controller is even hit.  I also do not wish to have to have special validation code inside my controller, it doesn't belong here by the architecture I am using.

How can I get the value in the javascript from ReCaptcha and set it to my hidden element so that my validation can take the proper course?  If this is not possible, how can I inside the validation attribute get the value if I do not have access to Request object that you get from your controller?

EDIT:

At the moment I have achieved this by importing HttpContext library and pulling the form out of the request that way.  I am wondering if there is another way to accomplish this, one that doesn't involve me importing HttpContext?

Comment: Are you using Explicit rendering or implicit rendering?

Comment: @FilipCordas I'm sorry I have no idea what you are asking me.

Comment: when you use [Explicit rendering] (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) you have a  data-callback callback The user's response, g-recaptcha-response, will be the input for your callback function.

Comment: Sorry my bad no need to use Explicit rendering just use data-callback. And in the function set the input field